# MySQL - WHERE clause coupled with LEFT JOIN?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, mysql-error-1064

Into a MYSQL query, I am trying to insert a WHERE clause (the one that appears in the PHP comment below). Whenever I place this clause in the MYSQL query statement, it always fails (I've tried both before the LEFT JOIN and before the ORDER BY clauses).

Any ideas on how I can get my statement to work?

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * 
                         FROM Items 
                    LEFT JOIN Topics on Topics.TopicID = Items.FK_TopicID 
                     ORDER BY TopicSort, TopicName ASC, ItemSort, ItemTitle");
/* WHERE FK_UserID=$_SESSION[user_id] */
$topicname = false;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!$row['TopicID']) {
            $row['TopicName'] = 'Sort Me';
    }
if ($topicname != $row['TopicName']) {
    echo '<ul><li>' . $row['TopicName'] . '</li><ul>';
    $topicname = $row['TopicName'];
}
echo '';
echo '<li>' . $row['ItemTitle'] . '</li>';
echo '';
}
    if ($topicname != $row['TopicName']) {
    echo '</ul>';
    $topicname = $row['TopicName'];
}

?>
```

Comment: What does "it fails" mean? You get an error message? You get data, but not the data you want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQL stands for **Structured** Query Language -- you can't put a WHERE clause wherever you want in the query.  The WHERE clause has to be after the FROM/JOIN clauses, and before the GROUP BY, HAVING, and ORDER BY clauses.  IE:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM ITEMS i
LEFT JOIN TOPICS t ON t.TopicID = i.FK_TopicID 
    WHERE FK_UserID = $_SESSION[user_id]
 ORDER BY TopicSort, TopicName ASC, ItemSort, ItemTitle
```

A better option, to insulate yourself from SQL injection attacks, is to use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * 
                  FROM ITEMS i
             LEFT JOIN TOPICS t ON t.TopicID = i.FK_TopicID 
                 WHERE FK_UserID = %u
              ORDER BY TopicSort, TopicName ASC, ItemSort, ItemTitle",
               mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION[user_id]));

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance. I put it in the order as outlined and I am still getting the following error. I would like to sprintf to protect myself from injection attacks, but I figured I would get the original to work first. The mysql_fetch_array works fine without the WHERE clause, but I need to limit it to just the single user_id.

'Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in'

Answer (score 1):

Put the WHERE clause before the ORDER BY clause.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

```
"SELECT * FROM Items LEFT JOIN Topics on Topics.TopicID = Items.FK_TopicID WHERE whateverTableTheFK_UserIDColumnIs.FK_UserID='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ORDER BY TopicSort, TopicName ASC, ItemSort, ItemTitle"
```

Comment: Thanks all. I was also missing the whateverTableTheFK_UserIDColumnIs.FK_UserID. Very helpful! I am going to learn more about Structured Query Language! :)